# How to display short information in list content?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ckeditor

I have already made data in my database. It made from ckeditor5. It looks like here [image]

The data mentions many tags and attributes. so... I just need to get the words inside tag p only. So I can display on my website. The example of the result is here:
[image]

Note: I just need to show 100 letters. And add '...' in the last sentence.

My last code looks like this:

```js
function removeTags(str) {
  if ((str === null) || (str === ''))
    return false;
  else
    str = str.toString();

  // Regular expression to identify HTML tags in  
  // the input string. Replacing the identified  
  // HTML tag with a null string. 
  return str.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '');
}
```

```html
<?php
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

echo '
<script>
  document.write(removeTags(
    '.$row['main_article'].'));
</script>';

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For truncating text, you can use this function.

```js
function truncateString(str, num) {
// str = character length
  if (str.length <= num) {
    return str
  }
  return str.slice(0, num) + '...'
}

truncateString("A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket", 8);
```

*Source: https://medium.com/@DylanAttal/truncate-a-string-in-javascript-41f33171d5a8*

Comment: ow.. im sorry, but i just found my sollution.
but i appreciate your efforts. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Here it is, and hopefully someone need this in future for his ckeditor content:

```html
<p><?php 

$str = strip_tags($row['main_article']);
$str = substr($str, 0, 200) . '...';
echo $str;

?></p>
```